# Error : Syntax error found at EOF

Tags: smlnj

I am running this code in SMLNJ.

```
val evenfibs=
let
  fun SIFT NIL = NIL
  | SIFT l =
       CONS(0, fn () =>
                    SIFT(FILTER (fn x => x mod 2 == 0) (TL l) ) );

val oddfibs=
let
  fun SIFT NIL = NIL
      | SIFT l =
       CONS(0, fn () =>
                    SIFT(FILTER (fn x => x mod 2 <> 0) (TL l) ));
```

assign3.sml:60.1 Error: syntax error found at EOF

```
uncaught exception Compile [Compile: "syntax error"]
  raised at: ../compiler/Parse/main/smlfile.sml:15.24-15.46
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:296.17-296.20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some hints :

Comparing is not done by `==` but `=`

Using a let needs closing like

```
let
 declarations
in
 expression
end
```

EOF usually occurs when you forgot to put some semi-colons or forgot to close stuff like let-in-end :)